# Run db action in yesod test

Tags: haskell, testing, integration-testing, yesod, yesod-test

In my yesod test I want to be able to modify a record in the db in the middle of the test.

Here is the code I came up with

```
        yit "post is created by authorized user" $ do
            request $ do
                addPostParam "ident" "dummy"
                setMethod "POST"
                setUrl ("http://localhost:3000/auth/page/dummy" :: Text)
            update 0 [UserAuthorized =. True]
            postBody PostR (encode $ object [
                "body" .= ("test post" :: Text),
                "title" .= ("test post" :: Text),
                "coverImage" .= ("test post" :: Text),
                "author" .= (0 :: Int)
                ])
            statusIs 200
```

This fails with the error

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
              with actual type ‘ReaderT backend0 m0 ()’
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘update 0 [UserAuthorized =. True]’

  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    runIO $ update 0 [UserAuthorized =. True]
  In the expression:
    do { settings <- runIO
                     $ loadYamlSettings
                         ["config/test-settings.yml", "config/settings.yml"] [] useEnv;
         foundation <- runIO $ makeFoundation settings;
         yesodSpec foundation $ do { ydescribe "Auth" $ do { ... } };
         runIO $ update 0 [UserAuthorized =. True];
         .... }
```

I can tell this is because `update` returns `m ()` instead of `YesodExample site ()` like `request`, `postBody` and `statusIs` do.

How would I be able to do a db update inside of this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 problems in this, the first one as Sibi pointed out is I needed `runDB` the second one is you can't just look up a record with an integer.

To get this working I used the following code

```
runDB $ do
    (first :: Maybe (Entity User)) <- selectFirst [] []
    case first of
        Nothing -> pure () -- handle the case when the table is empty
        Just (Entity k _) -> update k [UserAuthorized =. True]
```

This find's the record in the DB and then updates it. Modify `(first :: Maybe (Entity User)) <- selectFirst [] []` to select the record you want to update.

Comment: And why the heck you can't lookup a record with an integer? It seems I encountered the same issues on my side.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `runDB` function. i.e:

```
runDB $ update 0  [UserAuthorized =. True]
```

Comment: This solved half of it, I have almost finished solving the other issue which I will post soon.